# Is there a test suite for verifying a QT port?

Tags: qt

We have ported parts of Qt to a an OS that is not supported by Nokia. The port seems to work, but how can we know for sure? It would be great if there was a test suite that we could use to verify our port. Is there such a test suite available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are Qt unit tests developed alongside Qt in the public git repo.

http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt , see the directory `tests/auto`.

You won't be able to run all of the tests yourself, and not all of them are expected to pass, but you should be able to make use of most of them.